# Convert string to a function in ruby-on-rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I need a method that through an input string to do a calculation, like this

```
function = "(a/b)*100"
a = 25
b = 50
function.something
>> 50
```

have some method for it?

Comment: If you are too confident use `Kernel#eval`... Like `eval(function)`.

Comment: I don't know what you want to do with it but please **do not trust user's input**, i.e. do not use something coming from end-users in your "string to be evaluated".

Comment: My honest suggestion is.. Please change your interface, so that you don't need to use any such `#eval`. Think it some other way. No point to use any *eval family* in doing such *math*.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `instance_eval`:

```
function = "(a/b)*100"
a = 25.0
b = 50

instance_eval function
# => 50.0
```

Be aware though that using eval is inherently insecure, especially if you use external input, as it may contain injected malicious code.

Also note that `a` is set to `25.0` instead of `25`, since if it is an integer `a/b` would result in `0` (integer).

Comment: Beware, this can run anything in your application, ex: User.destroy_all.

Comment: @BrunoMuceliniMergen, yes, I've mentioned that in my answer

Comment: @RustamA.Gasanov Something is saving your time.. Doesn't mean it is clean,superb and all.. It can take whole life of the app.. Be sure always.

Answer (score 3):

You can take a look at the gem [`dentaku`](https://github.com/rubysolo/dentaku), which is math and logic formula parser and evaluator.

```
require 'dentaku'

a = 25.0
b = 50
function = "(#{a}/#{b})*100"

calculator = Dentaku::Calculator.new
calculator.evaluate(function) # => 50.0
```

Don't use any *eval*.

Comment: "Don't use any eval." There is a time and a place for `eval`. `eval` is fine when you *know* what's being eval'd. If the string is created by the script, and is based on sanitized data then it's safe. It's unsafe when the data is unknown/not-sanitized.

Comment: @theTinMan You are right. But still I will practice the good habit of not using `eval`, and I will look for a *math parser*, like the one I have shown here. I don't support,`eval` using, where there is a way. `#instance_eval` or `#instance_exec` has other purposes, but not they are for mathematical calculations.. Any way it is matter of taste, about avoiding risk.

Comment: formula shall stay `"(a/b)*100"` and then add the variables `{a: 25.0, b: 50}` to the `evaluate`